# How can I assign a specific id to company

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a code that i have to fix:

```
DECLARE @Maxx int, @id int, @sql nvarchar(max), @Company nvarchar(50), @unionall nvarchar(11);
    
    set @id = 1;
    set @sql = '';

      set @Maxx  = ( SELECT MAX(a.rn)  Maxxx
      FROM ( SELECT  Company, 
      ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Company) as rn
      FROM dbo.Companies)a)

     WHILE @id <= @Maxx
    BEGIN
    
      set @Company = ( SELECT Company
      FROM (
      SELECT  Company,
      ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Company) as rn
      FROM dbo.Companies) a WHERE a.rn = @id  )
      
    
       if (@id = 1) BEGIN 
       set @unionall = '' END 
       ELSE BEGIN set @unionall = ' UNION ALL '  END
    
    set @sql = @sql + @unionall + 
    'SELECT
          CAST('+ CAST(@id AS nvarchar(2)) +' as nvarchar(2)) + ''@'' + [No_]+ ''@'' as PartnerKey
   ,[No_]
          ,[Name]
          ,[City]
          ,[Customer_Vendor Segment]
          ,[Country_Region Code]
          ,[County]
      ,''Cust'' as DebtType
      FROM /*Existing data base.*/[dbo].[' + @Company + '$Customer]
  
      UNION ALL

      SELECT 
          CAST('+ CAST(@id AS nvarchar(2)) +' as nvarchar(2)) + ''@'' + [No_]+ ''@'' as PartnerKey
      ,[No_]
          ,[Name]
          ,[City]
          ,[Customer_Vendor Segment]
          ,[Country_Region Code]
          ,[County]
      ,''Vend'' as DebtType
      FROM /*Existing data base.*/[dbo].[' + @Company + '$Vendor]
      '
     
      set @id = @id +1
      END
    
    exec (@sql);
```

My table, named Companies, has 2 columns: id and Company:

[image]

Code is working fine, although @id gets values 1,2,3 as there are 3 company names in the table Companies. The problem is, that I have to fix the loop that @id in PartnerKey gets values 1,2,5. How do I fix this loop?

Comment: The *real* problem is is your design; Why are you using the table name to store the name of the company, when the name of the company should be a column in a table called `Vendor`. Also `'...[' + @Variable + N']...'` is **not** safe against injection.

Comment: This code and table "Companies" was premade for me for learning purposes.